# List orders history using Customer token?

Tags: magento2, api, rest-api

There is no option to get all customer orders without setting there admin rights. So is there is an API to call like `/V1/orders/mine` ?

Comment: Who this voted down? Is he understood the question firstly?

Comment: I voted down cause question is not clear (for me ofc). Also if issue is with api auth, you could use google for find it easily ^^  Eh, I will reject downvote. I could also write it instead downvote. I will be able do that if you edit post

Comment: YOU DON"T UNDERSTAND ANY THING. I DON"T  WANT TO USE GOOGLE AUTH ^^ Eh BECAUSE OF SECURITY. I WANT TO USER RENEWABLE SESSIONS, SO I AM USING CUSTOMER TOKENS. READ THE FOLLOEING POST AND COMMENTS CAREFULLY.  [https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/3552 ]. REMOVE VOTEDOWN

Comment: I doesn't write about google auth XD just about use google for find solution ^^ As I wrote I am not able to remove votedown until you edit post. It is not my 'humour' - just info when I am trying do that ;)

Comment: anyway on magento swager you have listed all allowed methods.

Comment: I SAID YOU ARE NOT UNDERSTOOD. BF

Answer (score -1):

/mine ?
What exactly You want?

http://devdocs.magento.com/swagger/#/
There is list all of default magento's 2 apis.
Also here is list of  rest apis:
http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/rest/list.html

There is Magento doc about api auth ;)
http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/get-started/authentication/gs-authentication-token.html - Also about customers token.

Comment: I mean this API `/V1/orders/` needs an admin token. and I don't want to use it for security. I need to use customer token.

Comment: Why you voted down the question

Comment: I edited my post